# Gmail header data

Tags: google-apps-script

Hopefully I can make this understandable as I am not a programmer.

I have an email that I believe the header information is correct but the content has been altered.
In the content portion of the header in every gmail that I have sent/forwarded there is an original text version of the email content and an HTML version which is limited to 76 characters and each sentence ends with an =.

This occurs whether the sentence was a complete sentence or if the email servers cut the words into 2 sections like this. 
"little boy blue ju=
mped over the moon"=

When the line hit 75 characters it inserted the = sign and moved the rest of the word to the next line

This creates a perfectly square box of text.

Now, I have an email where I believe the almost clever individual attempted to spoof the content part of the header data but instead completed each sentence with a =20 then moved to the next line. No words were cropped and the context is not in a perfect square as it is on every other email header I have inspected.

Also, when an email is forwarded each line is prefaced with a > or a >> which is not the case in this particular email.

Additionally in the HTML portion of the emails the paragraph will end with additional coding such as...

In the HTML code used in Gmails headers, what does the =20 designate?

Also, based on the minimal amount of information I have supplied to you am I correct in believing the content may be spoofed?